# Cannot include outlets in file

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, outlet

I created a storyboard with a navigation controller inside. The View inside the nav controller contains a MKMapView. Now I want to create an Outlet in my viewController.m file. But when I try to connect from storyboard to the viewcontroller.m file using the assistant editor, nothing happens, and I am not allowed to connect the outlet to this file.

Did I miss something? Why can I not connect the file?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your MFnotuf controller on storyboard is inherits your ViewController class[image]